# Extract all characters after a match - shell script

Tags: shell

I am in need to extract all characters after a pattern match.

For example ,

`NAME=John`

`Age=16`

I need to extract all characters after "=". Output should be like

`John`

`16`

I cant go with perl or Jython for this purpose because of some restrictions.
I tried with grep , but to my knowledge I came as shown below only

`echo "NAME=John" |grep -o -P '=.{0,}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close:

```
grep -oP '(?<=\w=)\w+' file
```

makes it.

#### Explanation

it looks for any word after `word=` and prints it.

- `-o` stands for *"Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line"*.
- `-P` stands for *"Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression"*.
- `(?<=\w=)\w+` means: match only `\w+` following `word=`. More info in [Regex tutorial - Lookahead][1] and in [this nice explanation by sudo_O][2].

#### Test

```
$ cat file
NAME=John
Age=16
$ grep -oP '(?<=\w=)\w+' file
John
16
```

Answer (score 0):

One sed solution

```
sed -ne 's/.*=//gp' <filename>
```

another awk solution

```
awk -F= '$0=$2' <filename>
```

Explanation:

in `sed` we remove anything from the beginning of a line till a `=` and print the rest. 
in `awk` we break the string in 2 parts, separated by `=`, now after that `$0=$2` is making replacing the whole string with the second portion