# How to extract all characters after the first match, without including the first match

Tags: regex

I have these strings, and I'm looking to extract all characters after the first `_`. For example:

```
'hello _I _ am _ 123312'
'Nobody sa_dwdq casc_as _ 1233_12'
'_dosjadojs aod jao jdaso j'
```

The output expected:

```
' I _ am _ 123312'
'dwdq casc_as _ 1233_12'
'dosjadojs aod jao jdaso j'
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210387/extract-all-characters-after-a-match-shell-script) is the closest answer I found, but it's not in BigquerySQL language.

And this is what I have got so far, but it includes the matched character and I haven't found a way to not include the matched character through regex:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(str, r'_.*')
```

Comment: Why is there a space before the `I` in the first expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it,

https://regex101.com/r/voPDE5/3

```
_(.*)
```

```
_ : Non Capturing group, matching exactly one occurrence of "_"  
(.*) : Captures the remainder of the string
```

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor, your edit made it even simpler.  Regards

Comment: Yeah, `(?:a){1}(?:b){1}(?:c){1}` = `abc`

Answer (score 1):

Use `REGEXP_REPLACE` instead to match what you *don't* want and delete that by replacing with blank:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(str, r'^.*?_', '')
```